# float.h not found or included properly when using mingw-w64

Tags: c++, c, include-path, mingw-w64, mxe

I'm trying to cross-compile a piece of code which uses float.h to set some FPU sizes.

The particular piece of code that requires it is:

```
#ifdef SINGLE
  _control87(_PC_24, _MCW_PC); /* Set FPU control word for single precision. */
#else /* not SINGLE */
  _control87(_PC_53, _MCW_PC); /* Set FPU control word for double precision. */
#endif /* not SINGLE */
```

When I compile, however, I get the error

```
/home/rcrozier/src/xfemm-hg/mfemm/../cfemm/fmesher/triangle.c:4922:14: error: '_PC_53' undeclared (first use in this function)
   _control87(_PC_53, _MCW_PC); /* Set FPU control word for double precision. */
```

Another person explains what seems to be the same problem in more detail [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/discussion/general/thread/0b04fcbd/#9d9a). There is also a very similar issue described in a (rather old) thread  [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/message/28824347/). In case it's relevant, I'm using `mingw-w64`, but via the [M Cross Environment](http://www.mxe.cc)

What exactly is the problem with `float.h` in this case, and is there a workaround?

**EDIT: Verbose output from gcc**

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-gcc
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared
Configured with: /opt/mxe/tmp-gcc-x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/gcc-4.9.4/configure --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=/opt/mxe/usr --libdir=/opt/mxe/usr/lib --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,fortran --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-nls --disable-multilib --without-x --disable-win32-registry --enable-threads=win32 --enable-libgomp --with-gmp=/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-isl=/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-mpc=/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-mpfr=/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-cloog=/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --with-as=/opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-as --with-ld=/opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-ld --with-nm=/opt/mxe/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-nm
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.9.4 (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-c' '-I' '../cfemm/fmesher' '-I' '../cfemm/libfemm' '-I' '../cfemm/libfemm/liblua' '-I' '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include' '-I' '/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/simulink/include' '-D' 'MATLAB_MEX_FILE' '-std=c99' '-D' '_GNU_SOURCE' '-fexceptions' '-fPIC' '-fno-omit-frame-pointer' '-pthread' '-v' '-fpermissive' '-D' 'CPU86' '-D' 'MX_COMPAT_32' '-O' '-D' 'NDEBUG' '-o' '/home/rcrozier/src/xfemm-hg/mfemm/../cfemm/fmesher/triangle.o' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /opt/mxe/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/4.9.4/cc1 -quiet -v -I ../cfemm/fmesher -I ../cfemm/libfemm -I ../cfemm/libfemm/liblua -I /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include -I /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/simulink/include -D_REENTRANT -U_REENTRANT -D MATLAB_MEX_FILE -D _GNU_SOURCE -D CPU86 -D MX_COMPAT_32 -D NDEBUG /home/rcrozier/src/xfemm-hg/mfemm/../cfemm/fmesher/triangle.c -quiet -dumpbase triangle.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase-strip /home/rcrozier/src/xfemm-hg/mfemm/../cfemm/fmesher/triangle.o -O -std=c99 -version -fexceptions -fPIC -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fpermissive -o /tmp/ccMkwwWD.s
cc1: warning: command line option '-fpermissive' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
GNU C (GCC) version 4.9.4 (x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.4, GMP version 6.1.1, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.2
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/4.9.4/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/sys-include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 ../cfemm/fmesher
 ../cfemm/libfemm
 ../cfemm/libfemm/liblua
 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include
 /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/simulink/include
 /opt/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/4.9.4/include
 /opt/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/4.9.4/include-fixed
 /opt/mxe/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/4.9.4/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared/include
End of search list.
```

**EDIT: more info**

I also get the same result if I use the full directory path to the `mingw-w64` `float.h` like so:

```
//#include <float.h>
#include "/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/include/float.h"
```

**EDIT more info on code structure**

To give some further information, I am actually compiling C library (header and C file) where declaration of the function I'm using is included using `extern C`. The actual declaration from the header file is shown below:

```c
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef ANSI_DECLARATORS
int triangulate(char *, struct triangulateio *, struct triangulateio *,
                 struct triangulateio *, int (*TriMessage)(const char * format, ...));
void trifree(VOID *memptr);
#else /* not ANSI_DECLARATORS */
int triangulate();
void trifree();
#endif /* not ANSI_DECLARATORS */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

The actual library I'm using is [Triangle](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html). The float.h include is in triangle.c, and looks like this:

```
#ifdef CPU86
//#include <float.h>
#include "/opt/mxe/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static/include/float.h"
#endif /* CPU86 */
#ifdef LINUX
#include <fpu_control.h>
#endif /* LINUX */
```

Where you define `CPU86` or `LINUX` at compile time. For the cross build, I'm defining `CPU86`.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? You expect float.h to define _PC_53 to something? **Why?**

Comment: It's what my googling indicated, does it not? Do you know the real issue?

Comment: No: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfloat The real issue is hard to tell, but probably a configuration issue.

Comment: Ahh, I wonder if I need to add some info. I'm actually compiling a C file included as extern in a C++ program.

Comment: Hmm ... do I understand that correctly: you're building on Linux (64 bit?) for host windows 64 bit? (x86_64?)

Comment: Yes, that's correct, cross-building for Windows 64 Bit on Linux 64 Bit host.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some searching around I found this in triangle.c:

```
/* On some machines, my exact arithmetic routines might be defeated by the   */
/*   use of internal extended precision floating-point registers.  The best  */
/*   way to solve this problem is to set the floating-point registers to use */
/*   single or double precision internally.  On 80x86 processors, this may   */
/*   be accomplished by setting the CPU86 symbol for the Microsoft C         */
/*   compiler, or the LINUX symbol for the gcc compiler running on Linux.    */
/*                                                                           */
```

Note that it says "*On 80x86 processors*". The host you're compiling for - windows 64 bit (x86_64) -  does not match that.

This is further supported by the [official documentation from Microsoft about the extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9b52ceh.aspx) that's used by the library you're trying to compile:

> Mask
>
> _MCW_PC (Precision control)
>
> (**Not supported** on ARM or **x64** platforms.)
>
> [..]
>
> _PC_24 (24 bits)
>
> _PC_53 (53 bits)
>
> _PC_64 (64 bits)
>
> [..]

Thus I guess you need to configure your build differently, probably not defining `CPU86`. Though I don't know whether this really solves your issue, or just leads to wrong results. After all ... is this library even ported to 64 bit?

Comment: You make a good point, but, I've now had a chance to double check, and I can confirm that the same code does compile and run natively on Windows, using the mingw-w64 compiler (specifically the version in TDM-GCC 4.9.2). So while this is something to worry about, I don't think this is the issue. I did actually email the original author about this some time ago but he never replied. I can definitely confirm that it compiles on 64 Bit Linux and has solved many many problems without issue.

Comment: I've now also had a chance to check triangle.c, and the help text at the beginning specifically mentions 64 bit architectures (he mentions the DEC Alpha in the context of recommending whether to use single of double precision), so I think in principle `triangle` should work on 64 Bit and practice indicates this is the case.

Comment: Hmm ... and in these working builds, is there `CPU86` defined? Reading the readme file, I'd just leave it (as well as `LINUX`) undefined. Can you try that?

Comment: Yes, `CPU86` is defined. I wonder if on windows x64, the setting is ignored but the default just happens to be the same as this setting (i.e. standard double, no extended floating point precision) and it works. I will try just not defining it and see what happens. This might cure the symptom which is useful (thanks!) but doesn't actually explain why cross build fails but native doesn't (both using mingw-w64).